# Motion of three points located at the vertices of an equilateral triangle

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

Given position vectors of three points $\vec{P_1}, \vec{P_2} \& \vec{P_3}$ as function of time $(t)$

$$\vec{P_m} = p_{mx}(t) \hat{i} + p_{my}(t) \hat{j}  : m \in \{1,2,3\}$$

These three points are located at the vertices of an equilateral triangle whose side equals $a$. They all start moving simulataneously the velocity $v$ constant in modulus, with first point heading continually for the second, the second for the third, and the third for the first. Initial positions for the points first lies at $(-\frac{a}{2},0)$, second at $(\frac{a}{2},0)$, and third at $(0,\sqrt{3}\frac{a}{2})$

1. Find the scalar function $p_{mx}(t)$ and $p_{my}(t)$ $\forall{m} \in {1,2,3}$
2. All three velocity vectors as a function of time.
3. Find all three scalar functions, $ \widehat{acceleration}_{m}(t)\cdot\widehat{velocity}_{m}(t)$, as a function of time.

Comment: I am able to solve $3^{rd}$ sub-question but not able to make headway in first two.

Comment: Let velocities be $\vec{V_m}$, acceleration be $\vec{A_m}$ and relative velocities $\in {\vec(V_{lm}): l \neq m, l,m \in {1,2,3} }$
$\vec{V_m} = v \widehat{(\vec{P_l} - \vec{P_m})} : \forall{(l,m)} \in \{(2,1),(3,2),(1,3)\} $
$\implies\sum_{l,m} \vert{\vec{P_{lm}} }\vert\vec{V_m} = 0$

Comment: After taking dericative of $\vec{V_m}$ we get
$\vec{A_m} = v \bigl( \frac{\vec{V_{lm}}}{\vert\vec{P_{lm}}\vert} -\frac{\frac{d\vert\vec{P_{lm}}\vert}{dt}}{(\vert\vec{P_{lm}}\vert)^2}\vec{P_{lm}}\bigr)$

evaluating, $\frac{d\vert\vec{P_{lm}}\vert}{dt} = \frac{\vec{P_{lm}}\cdot\vec{V_{lm}}}{\vert\vec{P_{lm}}\vert}$ gives $\vec{A_m} = \frac{v}{\vert\vec{P_{lm}}\vert} \bigl( \vec{V_{lm}} -\frac{\vec{P_{lm}}\cdot\vec{V_{lm}}}{(\vert\vec{P_{lm}}\vert)^2}\vec{P_{lm}}\bigr)$

Comment: $\vec{A_m} \cdot \vec{V_m} = \bigl(\frac{v}{\vert\vec{P_{lm}}\vert}\bigr)^2 \bigl(\vec{P_{lm}}\cdot\vec{V_{lm}} - \vec{P_{lm}}\cdot\vec{V_{lm}}\bigr) = 0$
$\implies \widehat{\vec{A_m} \cdot \vec{V_m}} = 0$

constant speed on a curved path implies acceleration should be perpendicular to velocity at all times.

Comment: Let me suggest that all of this stuff that you put in the comments should be part of your question. Furthermore, you should ask a specific question, and you should explain where exactly you got stuck on this problem. As it stands, your post itself is simply a demand for a solution with no actual question, and that kind of post often attracts close votes. See also [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for some general tips on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the feedback. I'll frame it better/specific now.